# PUN 2 | Cant dynamically add players child transform to transform array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, camera, multiplayer

Im using the following Camera script (link) for all players. The script zooms in and out to capture all players. There are 4 players total in game. Testing with 2 right now. I cannot get the child object of the network player (the Kitty_Orange's transform) to automatically attach to the camera.
Child object has the Player tag.
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/camera-control?projectId=5c5149c5edbc2a001fd5be95#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b398

I have a GameSetupController.cs that instantiates the player into the scene. This seems the most appropriate place to add the transform of the avatar to the camera. When player enters game scene I get a null reference.

Error when trying to dynamically add transforms to Camera m_Targets transform array.
**WITH DEBUG**

```
      Debug.Log("CC.m_Targets.Length" + CC.m_Targets.Length);  //Troubleshooting  
      CC.m_Targets = new Transform[players.Length]; // array of size 1-4  
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 GameSetupController.CreatePlayer () (at Assets/InfoGamerPhoton/Scripts/GameSetupController.cs:33)
 GameSetupController.Start () (at Assets/InfoGamerPhoton/Scripts/GameSetupController.cs:14)
```

**WITHOUT DEBUG**

```
         CC.m_Targets = new Transform[players.Length]; // array of size 1-4
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 GameSetupController.CreatePlayer () (at Assets/InfoGamerPhoton/Scripts/GameSetupController.cs:34)
 GameSetupController.Start () (at Assets/InfoGamerPhoton/Scripts/GameSetupController.cs:14)
```

CameraControl.cs

```
 public Transform[] m_Targets; // All the targets the camera needs to encompass. [HideInInspector]
```

GameSetupController.cs

```
 using Photon.Pun;
 using System.IO;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class GameSetupController : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private CameraControl CC;
     public GameObject[] players;
 // This script will be added to any multiplayer scene
 void Start()
 {
     CC = GetComponent<CameraControl>();
     CreatePlayer(); //Create a networked player object for each player that loads into the multiplayer scenes.
     
 }
 private void CreatePlayer()
 {
     Debug.Log("Creating Player");
     PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "PhotonPlayer"), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
     players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
     if (players.Length == 0)
     {
         return;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
     {
         Debug.Log("players.Length" + players.Length);  //Troubleshooting
         Debug.Log("CC.m_Targets.Length" + CC.m_Targets.Length);  //Troubleshooting
         CC.m_Targets = new Transform[players.Length]; // array of size 1-4
         Debug.Log(CC.m_Targets.Length);
         Debug.Log(players.Length);
         CC.m_Targets[i] = players[i].transform;
         Debug.Log("m_Targets : " + CC.m_Targets[i]);
         Debug.Log("players : " + players[i]);
     }
 }
```

}

[image]
[image: player]

#### My Temp Solution - inside CameraControl.cs

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        m_Targets = new List<Transform>();

        //ADDS PLAYERS TO THE M_TARGETS LIST!
        players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        foreach (GameObject child in players) 
        {
            //Debug.Log(child.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0));
            m_Targets.Add(child.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0));
            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CC object is null, that's where the Null references are coming from. `GetComponent` will only find Components attached to the same GameObject as the script invoking it. If the objects are added to the scene statically in editor, you can use `[SerializeField]` attribute to make the private object visible in inspector and assign the reference manually. `Find` methods are generally expensive, so if you can avoid using them by storing the references in a common place or setting them up beforehand, that's the recommended approach.

Comment: I would love to be able to just assign them however as the game has a list of avatars to choose from for multiplayer I cannot statically assign it.  I did come up with this piece.  You said finds are expensive.  Let me know what you think of this.  I updated at the bottom of Q.

Comment: You're still using a find every single frame. An approach I used in the past was to have a static class that stores game-wide data (e.g. GameData) and I would initialise certain parts of it at certain stages of the game (e.g. in my lobby I'd initialise GameData.Players[]), and use them later (e.g. in actual game retrieve GameData.Players). Also while "Finds" are expensive, it's fine to use them now and then (e.g. once to initialise Players property). For a non-AAA title there's going to be little to no impact unless used wrong. It's just good practice to avoid that where you can.